# Any tool to check function's resource consumption?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. Is there any built in tool that I can use to check how how much resources does my functions are consuming? Or is there any other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 has a profiler to find bottenecks (time is a resource right?)

- [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)

There is also the CLR Profiler: [How To: Use CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx)

- [CLR Profiler for the .NET Framework 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en) (can be used with .NET 3.5)
- [CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1)

(Also: [Visual Studio Profiler Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/))